# How to find string(conaining special char) from regular expression with boundary condition

Tags: regex, boundary

Below is my string from which i want to find substring:

pull if {{MySQL}}.EmployeePerson!.City is 'Seattle' then {{MySQL}}.EmployeePerson!.StateProvinceID else '0' as StateProvinceID from {{MySQL}}.EmployeePerson!

and here is my regular expression

EmployeePerson!\b

so i need to find "EmployeePerson!" string but i am not able to get any result , so please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `EmployeePerson!`, as `!` is already a non-word char. Or `EmployeePerson!\B`

Comment: Thanks its working fine........

Comment: I am not finding word ending with EmployeePerson which where happening with '/b'

Comment: To find `EmployeePerson` as a whole word, just use `\bEmployeePerson\b`.

Comment: Example : pull if {{MySQL}}.CorpEmployeePerson!.City is 'Seattle' then {{MySQL}}.Person!.StateProvinceID else '0' as StateProvinceID from {{MySQL}}.EmployeePerson!

Answer (score 0):

When you put `\b` after `!`, you require a word char after `!`.

See [what word boundary matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Thus, you need to remove `\b` if you do not need to check the context after `!`, or replace `\b` with `\B` that will require a non-word char  or end of string.

To find `EmployeePerson!` as a whole word, just use

```
\bEmployeePerson!
```

or

```
\bEmployeePerson!\B
```

or - if you need to make sure there are spaces or start/end of string on both ends:

```
(?<!\s)EmployeePerson!(?!\s)
```

or - if you want to make sure there are no words chars on both ends:

```
(?<!\w)EmployeePerson!(?!\w)
```

Comment: EmployeePerson is editable here. I can give special char even in between as well as end eg: Employe#e@Person! . As its dynamic input.

Comment: See 2 more options for you